# VS2013 C++ Compiler Error C3860 workaround?

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++

I'm having the following code compile just fine with GCC 4.8.3 C++11 while with MSVC2013 it throws the following error on the definition of "DoSmth": 
C3860: template argument list following class template name must list parameters in the order used in template parameter list

Here's the code:

```
template <typename Bla3, typename Bla4>
class B
{
public:
    struct X
    {
        int a; 
        int b;
    };

    B() {}
    ~B() {}
};

template<typename Bla1, typename Bla2, typename Bla3>
class A
{
public:
    A() {}
    ~A() {}

    void DoSmth(struct B<Bla1, Bla3>::X var);
};


template<typename Bla1, typename Bla2, typename Bla3>
void A<Bla1, Bla2, Bla3>::DoSmth(struct B<Bla1, Bla3>::X var)
{

}
```

As I understand from the error link (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h2wky6zt.aspx) one would need to compile with /c in order to make this work, but that would prevent automatic linking.

Does anyone know why is this limitation of having to place the template parameters in the same order and if there is a way around this without changing the parameter order?

Comment: Known problem, workaround is to define the function inline.

Comment: Thanks, that works. Just to make it clear, implementation needs to be inside the class definition.

Answer (score 0):

This will work and might also make your code more readable

```
template <typename Bla3, typename Bla4>
class B
{
public:
    struct X
    {
        int a;
        int b;
    };

    B() {}
    ~B() {}
};

template<typename Bla1, typename Bla2, typename Bla3>
class A
{
public:

    typedef B<Bla1, Bla3>           B_Type;
    typedef struct B_Type::X        X_Type;

    A() {}
    ~A() {}

    void DoSmth(X_Type var);
};

template<typename Bla1, typename Bla2, typename Bla3>
void A<Bla1, Bla2, Bla3>::DoSmth(X_Type var)
{
}
```